# Plotting points with size adapting to number of data points (cex)

Tags: r, plot, tree

I have the following data from a `tree` analysis:

```
train = sample(1:nrow(dd),1010)  
yhat1 <- predict(tree.model1,newdata=dd[-train,])
v10.test <- dd$v10[-train]
```

`dd` is my data.frame, `v10` is the (discrete) response variable that varies between 1 and 10, and `train` is a sample drawn from my dataframe.

I want to plot the predictions `yhat1` with the actual test values `v10.test`, with the point size taking into account the number of actual test.values that are assigned to that `yhat1` as prediction.

Thus:

```
plot(yhat1, v10.test, cex = ???)
```

The values for cex that I need can be drawn from the table object, but I don't know how. Any ideas?

```
table(yhat1, dd.test)
                 v10.test
yhat1               0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
  2.99479166666667 17 26  7 21 10  8  7  7  8  3  6
  4.36725663716814  8 15 21 14 14 14 13 12  4  5  4
  4.75              1  1  3  1  0  2  2  2  1  1  0
  4.82710280373832  6 10  5 11  7 11 11 18 22  3  2
  5.73684210526316  1  5  1  9  7 13 10  7 12  7 12
  6.68              0  1  0  1  0  3  1  1  0  0  1
  6.92045454545455  0  2  3  2  5  5  4  7  6  9  6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `symbols` function may be preferable to using `plot` and `cex` when you want the size of points to depend on an additional variable.  Note that you will generally get the best representation when using the square root of the variable to determine size (so that the area is proportional).

Answer (score 1):

I played around a bit more and it turns out my main problem was not with the table but with the standard settings for `pch` and the standard size of the points, which made the resulting graph impossible to interpret.

So a way of doing it simply is

```
plot(yhat1, dd.test, pch = 20, cex = table(yhat1,v10.test)/10)
```

That does the trick (and shows how poor the data fit is)

Comment: You could also use `ggplot` with `stat_sum()`, which will automatically do this for you.